# how to check password on sweetAlert in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sweetalert2

I have been trying to check the user password on sweetAlert. But the `subscribe` method keeps executing last and doesn't work well. Is there any possible way I can make this work?
here is my code.

```
swal.fire({
  title: 'Confirm Password',
  input: 'password',
  confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
  focusConfirm: false,
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (password) => {
    if (password=='') {
      swal.showValidationMessage(`Please enter login and password`)
    }
    else {
      const userName = 'jhonDoe' 
      let a = this.checkPass(userName, password) // excuted 1st
      console.log(a)  // excuted 3rd  ---- which should display if the user password success or not
    }
  }
})


checkPass(userName,password) {
    this.userService.checkPassword(userName, password).subscribe((data: any) => { //excuted 2nd 
      setTimeout(() => {               //excuted 4th
        if (data.succeeded) {
          return data.succeeded
        } else {
          console.log(data.errors[0].description)
          return data.errors[0].code
        }
      }, 500)
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return err
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `userService.checkPassword` is an asynchronous method which returns an observable. The checkPass function dosnt return anything, since the returns are all in some abetrary sub functions.

```
function foo(){
    setIntervall(() => {return 0;}, 0)
}
```

will not return anything.

You need to use an async strategy. The easiest way would be to return a Promise:

```
function checkPass(userName: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.userService.checkPassword(userName, password).subscribe((data: any) => {
          if (data.succeeded) {
              resolve(data.succeeded);
          } else {
              console.log(data.errors[0].description)
              reject(data.errors[0])
          }
      },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              reject(err)
          });
  });
}
```

Afterwards you only need to await the result of the checkPass function, which isn't a problem since the method supports async results:

```
preConfirm: async (password) => {
  if (password == '') {
      swal.showValidationMessage(`Please enter login and password`)
  } else {
      const userName = 'jhonDoe'
      let a = await this.checkPass(userName, password) // excuted 1st
      console.log(a)  // excuted 3rd  ---- which should display if the user password success or not
  }
}
```